# Disable keyboard shortucts on a particular story in Storybook v7

Tags: reactjs, configuration, storybook

I have a particular component (out of many within storybook) that listens for keypresses after loading without anything having been focused.  I have a storybook story for this component, but it's kind of useless because the letters F, A, D, S, T, O, V, and M are used by the Storybook interface.

I understand that it's possible to [disable keyboard shortcuts in manager.js or preview.js or using the URL](https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/react/configure/features-and-behavior).

I haven't been able to get the URL approach to work (and [it seems I'm not the only one](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/23750)).

Maybe I should just wait for the PR to fix URL-based approach to get merged and then upgrade once it's released; I'm on 7.0.2 at the moment.  But in that case I guess I'd need to figure out how to append `&enableShortcuts=false` to the story URL for that particular story in the story link in the left rail.

I don't want to try to have to defeat storybook's built in behavior for this code with JavaScript hacks, and I don't want to disable keyboard shortcuts in any of my other stories.  Is there any other way to do this?  Ideally I could set it in the `meta` or the `StoryObj`.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that it's possible to disable keyboard shortcuts in
> manager.js or preview.js or using the URL.

Have you tried to set

```
enableShortcuts: false,
```

as in the mentioned config?

Comment: I don’t want to disable keyboard shortcuts for _all_ stories, just this one. I’d like to do it at the component level.